# Brownian Motion construction - How is Perseval's identity applied? Why does the below fact imply the existence of limit?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, brownian-motion, parsevals-identity

In **Schilling, Partzsch**, referring to *Levy-Ciesielski construction of Brownian Motion*, I read that:

> [...] idea is to write the paths $[0,1]\ni t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ for almost every $\omega$ as a random series with respect to a complete orthonormal system (ONS) in the Hilbert space $L^2(dt)=L^2([0,1]\text{, }dt)$ with canonical scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2}=\displaystyle{\int_{0}^1f(t)g(t)dt}$. Assume that $(\phi_n)_{n\geq0}$ is any complete Orthonormal System and let $(G_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a sequence of real-valued iid Gaussian $\mathbb{N}(0,1)$ - random variables on the probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}\right)$. Set: 
> $$W_N(t):=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}G_n\langle\mathbb{1}_{[0,t)},\phi_n\rangle_{L^2}\tag{1}$$
> $$=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}G_n\displaystyle{\int}_0^t\phi_n(s)ds$$
>
> > **Lemma.** The limit $W(t):=\lim_{N\to\infty}W_N(t)$ exists for every $t\in[0,1]$ in $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ [...]
> > **Proof.** $\color{red}{\text{Using }}$ the independence of the $G_n\sim\mathbb{N}(0,1)$ and $\color{red}{\text{Parseval's identity}}$, we get for every $t\in[0,1]$
> > $$\mathbb{E}\left(W_N(t)^2\right)=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sum_{m,n=0}^{N-1}G_nG_m\langle1_{[0,t)},\phi_m\rangle_{L^2}\langle1_{[0,t)},\phi_n\rangle_{L^2}\bigg]\tag{2}$$
> > $$=\sum_{m,n=1}^{N-1}\mathbb{E}(G_nG_m)\langle1_{[0,t)},\phi_m\rangle_{L^2}\langle1_{[0,t)},\phi_n\rangle_{L^2}$$
> > $$=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\langle1_{[0,t)},\phi_n\rangle_{L^2}^2\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\langle 1_{[0,t)},1_{[0,t)}\rangle_{L^2}=t$$
> > $\color{red}{\text{This shows that }W(t)=L^2\text{-}\lim_{N\to\infty}W_N(t)\text{ exists}}$.

I have two doubts regarding the above parts in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$:

1. I guess that Parseval's identity is applied to $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\langle1_{[0,t)},\phi_n\rangle_{L^2}^2$ in $(2)$ before taking the limit as $N$ goes to $\infty$. But how does it happen? Could you please explicit such an application of the identity?;
2. Why does it hold true that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(W_N(t)^2\right)=t\implies W(t)=L^2\text{-}\lim_{N\to\infty}W_N(t)\text{ exists}$$
   ? Is this due to some basic probability theory result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

- Parseval identity is used in the last step, i.e. for
  $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left<\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]},\varphi _n\right>^2_{L^2}=\|\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]}\|^2_{L^2}=\left<\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]}, \boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]}\right>_{L^2}.$$
- For your other question, the fact that $$\lim_{N\to \infty }\mathbb E[W_N(t)^2]=t,$$ implies that $(W_N(t))_N$ is an $L^2(\mathbb P)-$Cauchy sequence.

---

**Edit**

One can prove that $$\mathbb E[W_n(t)W_m(t)]=\mathbb E[W_{n\wedge m}(t)^2],$$
and thus

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[(W_n(t)-W_m(t))^2]&=\underbrace{\mathbb E[W_n(t)^2]+\mathbb E[W_m(t)^2]-2\mathbb E[W_{n\wedge m}(t)^2]}_{\underset{n,m\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0}.
\end{align}

Comment: As to Parseval's identity, why $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left<\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]},\varphi _n\right>^2_{L^2}=\|\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]}\|^2_{L^2}$ and not  $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left<\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]},\varphi _n\right>^2_{L^2}=||\varphi_n||^2_{L^2}$? Finally,  could you please suggest me a reference for the second result (the one concerning the limit of the expectation of the second moment implying Cauchy sequence)? @Surb

Comment: I edited, it was my mistake (the sum must be infinite). For your last question, why don't you try to prove it your self ? Is not hard to prove it. @Strictly_increasing

Comment: In your reply I still see $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\left<\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]},\varphi _n\right>^2_{L^2}=\|\boldsymbol 1_{[0,t]}\|^2_{L^2}$ and I was wondering why that holds true (maybe I have not properly understood Parseval's identity). As to the second point, that's ok, I will try right now! @Surb

Comment: @Strictly_increasing: Yes, and this is exactly Parseval identity. In a Hilbert space $(H,\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>)$, if $\{\varphi _i\}_{i\in \mathcal I}$ is a orthonormal basis, then $$\sum_{i\in \mathcal I}\left<h,\varphi _i\right>^2=\|h\|^2.$$Namely, this is called Parseval identity.

Comment: As far as I understand, finiteness of the limit of the second moment "suggests" that we are in an $L^2$ context. However, I have tried to show rigorously that this fact implies that $\forall \epsilon$ s.t. $\exists N \text{s.t. } \forall g\text{, }h\geq N\text{, } |W_g(t)-W_h(t)|<\epsilon$, but I failed to. Could it be possible to have even a small hint/reference? @Surb

Comment: EDIT: $\forall \epsilon\text{ } \exists N\text{ s.t.}$ [...] @Surb

Comment: I edited my answer @Strictly_increasing

Comment: Thank you a lot. Obviously, it relies on the fact that every Cauchy sequence converges, doesn't it? @Surb

Comment: To the fact that all Cauchy sequence in $L^2$ converges (because $L^p$ are Banach spaces). It's not true in general that Cauchy sequences converges. @Strictly_increasing